# Software for organizing a folder

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

I have a folder with a lot of e-books and I want them to be organized in different categories both logically and visually. What I mean is to provide both a good way to access what I need easily and customize the folder so to have different "areas" under different tags. Is there any software that can make a folder organized in that way so to be able find my e-books and generally files easily?

Answer (score 1):

Calibre is a great ebook management tool. You can install it using -

`sudo apt-get install calibre`

> Calibre manages your e-book collection for you. It is designed around
>   the concept of the logical book, i.e., a single entry in your library
>   that may correspond to actual e-book files in several formats.
>
> Calibre can sort the books in your library by: Title, Author, Date
>   added, Date published, Size, Rating, Series, etc.
>
> In addition, it supports extra searchable metadata:
>
> ```
> Tags: A flexible system for categorizing your collection however you like
> Comments: A long form entry that you can use for book description, notes, reviews, etc.
> ```
>
> You can easily search your book collection for a particular book.
>   calibre supports searching any and all of the fields mentioned above.
>   You can construct advanced search queries by clicking the helpful
>   "Advanced search" button to the left of the search bar.
>
> You can export arbitrary subsets of your collection to your hard disk
>   arranged in a fully customizable folder structure.
>
> Finally, calibre will even go out onto the internet to find book
>   metadata based on existing title/author or ISBN information. It can
>   download various types of metadata and covers for your books,
>   automatically. The metadata system is written using plugins so that
>   different types of metadata sources can be supported in the future.

You can have a look at the other features [here](http://calibre-ebook.com/about).

Comment: Note that the Calibre website indicates that the version at various distros (like Ubuntu) is quite dated, and the version downloadable from [the website](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) installs very easily in Ubuntu.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Do you mean "outdated"?

Comment: @RegisteredUser Calibre version on Ubuntu Software Center:  2.5.0  --  Calibre Version on Calibre website:  2.11.0  ---  Quote from [Calibre Website](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) "Please do not use your distribution provided calibre package, as those are often buggy/outdated. Instead use the Binary install described below. "